# ¿Como romper el flujo de un script? y ¿como aplicar efectos en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

estoy trabajando en un mini proyecto personal y tengo un problema; cuando recargo la pagina en mi localhost, me sale bienvenido o datos registrado no cuando entro por primera vez claro esta, y quisiera saber si se puede romper el flujo de el script que tengo para que  no pase eso porque solamente aparece eso cuando le doy click al boton de iniciar sesion o registrar.

Y tambien quisiera saber si hay posibilidad colocar el php debajo del form justamente el div sin romper el efecto que le he aplicado, cada vez que coloco php debajo del form en el div me aplica el efecto pero si le coloco otro php en otro div donde tengo el iniciar sesión no me aplica el efecto ya que tiene dos require. Por eso lo coloque debajo de todo el html.

```
<pre><code>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Shop List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="loguin" id="loguin">
                <h3>Loguin</h3>
                <form action="index.php" method="POST" onsubmit="">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="correo">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="clave">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In" id="btn1" name="boton">
                <span>
                    <br>
                    <p>Dont have account?  <a id="sign" href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
                </span>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="registro" id="registro">
                <h3>Register</h3>
                <form action="index.php" method="POST" onsubmit="">
                    <input type="name" placeholder="Name" name="nombre">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="clave">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="clave2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create Account" name="boton" id="btn2">
                    <span>
                        <br>
                        <p>Log in your account! <a id="sign2"href="#">Sign In</a></p>
                    </span>
                </form>

            </div>

        </section>
        <script src="js/eventos.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```php
   <?php
   require ('php/connection.php');
             //Variables del formulario iniciar
             $correoUser = $_POST['correo'];
             $passUser = $_POST['clave'];
             $enviar2 = $_POST['boton'];

             if(isset($enviar2)){
               $conexion = new connection();
               $conexion->startSession($correoUser, $passUser);
           }


                      // Variables del formulario Registrar
                      $nomUser = $_POST['nombre'];
                      $correoUser2 = $_POST['email'];
                      $passUser1 = $_POST['clave'];
                      $passUser2 = $_POST['clave2'];
                      $enviar = $_POST['boton'];
                      // 
                      if(isset($enviar)){
                              echo "<script>alert('Datos Registrado')</script>";
                              $conexion = new connection();
                              $conexion->insertarDatos($nomUser, $correoUser2, $passUser1);
                       }

      ?>
```

Me registra y me compara los datos claro esta, pero no se donde colocar el php para validar los formularios y que me aplique el efecto. Si aplico el php en cada uno, debajo de los formulario es decir:

```php
   <form>
   </form>
   <?php 
   require('connection.php');
   ?>
   <form>
   </form>
   <?php 
   require('connection.php');
   ?>
```

Supondremos que esté asi, no me aplica dicho efecto, y creo que esta mal enlazar dos veces el require pienso yo qque es una mala practica. Que puedo hacer?

Comment: podrias cargar el js ? ayudaria para saber que script deseas parar

Comment: buenas federico disculpa la tardanza, es que no deseo parar el javascript, el codigo cuando coloco el php en una parte de la estructura del  html se rompe y en otras partes nop, y no se donde colocar mi codigo php para que haga el efecto mas funcione correctamente